# Unable to locate physical ASPX file from My-Profile using SPD 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to locate custom ASPX page from custom My-Profile sub menu apparently this location does not exist in SPD `/site/my/mycustompage.aspx`.

Any thoughts will be appreciated. TIA.

[image]

Comment: @Dato' Mohammad Nurdin ?